# Colab: (0) UNIMPLEMENTED: DNN library is not found

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, object-detection

I have pretrained model for object detection (Google Colab + TensorFlow) inside Google Colab and I run it two-three times per week for new images I have and everything was fine for the last year till this week. Now when I try to run model I have this message:

```
Graph execution error:

2 root error(s) found.
  (0) UNIMPLEMENTED:  DNN library is not found.
     [[{{node functional_1/conv1_conv/Conv2D}}]]
     [[StatefulPartitionedCall/SecondStagePostprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/Reshape_5/_126]]
  (1) UNIMPLEMENTED:  DNN library is not found.
     [[{{node functional_1/conv1_conv/Conv2D}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_restored_function_body_27380] ***
```

Never happended before.

Before I can run my model I have to install Tensor Flow object detection API with this command:

```py
import os

os.chdir('/project/models/research')

!protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
!cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
!python -m pip install .
```

This is the output of command:

```
Processing /content/gdrive/MyDrive/models/research
  DEPRECATION: A future pip version will change local packages to be built in-place without first copying to a temporary directory. We recommend you use --use-feature=in-tree-build to test your packages with this new behavior before it becomes the default.
   pip 21.3 will remove support for this functionality. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7555.
Collecting avro-python3
  Downloading avro-python3-1.10.2.tar.gz (38 kB)
Collecting apache-beam
  Downloading apache_beam-2.35.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (9.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 9.9 MB 1.6 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (4.2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (3.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Cython in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (0.29.27)
Requirement already satisfied: contextlib2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (0.5.5)
Collecting tf-slim
  Downloading tf_slim-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (352 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 352 kB 50.5 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycocotools in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (2.0.4)
Collecting lvis
  Downloading lvis-0.5.3-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (1.3.5)
Collecting tf-models-official>=2.5.1
  Downloading tf_models_official-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.2 MB 38.3 MB/s
Collecting tensorflow_io
  Downloading tensorflow_io-0.24.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (23.4 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 23.4 MB 1.7 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: keras in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (2.7.0)
Collecting opencv-python-headless
  Downloading opencv_python_headless-4.5.5.62-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (47.7 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 47.7 MB 74 kB/s
Collecting sacrebleu
  Downloading sacrebleu-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (90 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 90 kB 10.4 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: kaggle>=1.3.9 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.5.12)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil>=5.4.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (5.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: oauth2client in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (4.1.3)
Collecting tensorflow-addons
  Downloading tensorflow_addons-0.15.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (1.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.1 MB 37.8 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: gin-config in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-datasets in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (4.0.1)
Collecting sentencepiece
  Downloading sentencepiece-0.1.96-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.2 MB 37.5 MB/s
Collecting tensorflow-model-optimization>=0.4.1
  Downloading tensorflow_model_optimization-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (213 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 213 kB 42.7 MB/s
Collecting pyyaml<6.0,>=5.1
  Downloading PyYAML-5.4.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (636 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 636 kB 53.3 MB/s
Collecting tensorflow-text~=2.8.0
  Downloading tensorflow_text-2.8.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (4.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 4.9 MB 46.1 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: google-api-python-client>=1.6.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.12.10)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-hub>=0.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (0.12.0)
Collecting seqeval
  Downloading seqeval-1.2.2.tar.gz (43 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 43 kB 2.1 MB/s
Collecting tensorflow~=2.8.0
  Downloading tensorflow-2.8.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (497.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 497.5 MB 28 kB/s
Collecting py-cpuinfo>=3.3.0
  Downloading py-cpuinfo-8.0.0.tar.gz (99 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 99 kB 10.1 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth<3dev,>=1.16.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.35.0)
Requirement already satisfied: uritemplate<4dev,>=3.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: httplib2<1dev,>=0.15.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (0.17.4)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-httplib2>=0.0.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (0.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: google-api-core<3dev,>=1.21.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.26.3)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=40.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-api-core<3dev,>=1.21.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (57.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-api-core<3dev,>=1.21.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (2018.9)
Requirement already satisfied: googleapis-common-protos<2.0dev,>=1.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-api-core<3dev,>=1.21.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.54.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-api-core<3dev,>=1.21.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (2.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=14.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-api-core<3dev,>=1.21.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.12.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-api-core<3dev,>=1.21.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (3.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-auth<3dev,>=1.16.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (0.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa<5,>=3.1.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-auth<3dev,>=1.16.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-auth<3dev,>=1.16.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (4.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from kaggle>=1.3.9->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (2021.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from kaggle>=1.3.9->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.24.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from kaggle>=1.3.9->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from kaggle>=1.3.9->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (4.62.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-slugify in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from kaggle>=1.3.9->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (5.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from packaging>=14.3->google-api-core<3dev,>=1.21.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (3.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth<3dev,>=1.16.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0->google-api-core<3dev,>=1.21.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0->google-api-core<3dev,>=1.21.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: libclang>=9.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (13.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py>=2.9.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: astunparse>=1.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: gast>=0.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (0.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-pasta>=0.1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (3.10.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt>=1.11.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.13.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem>=0.23.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (0.23.1)
Collecting tf-estimator-nightly==2.8.0.dev2021122109
  Downloading tf_estimator_nightly-2.8.0.dev2021122109-py2.py3-none-any.whl (462 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 462 kB 49.5 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing>=1.1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.1.2)
Collecting tensorboard<2.9,>=2.8
  Downloading tensorboard-2.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 5.8 MB 41.2 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: flatbuffers>=1.12 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (2.0)
Collecting keras
  Downloading keras-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.4 MB 41.2 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: opt-einsum>=2.3.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (3.3.0)
Collecting numpy>=1.15.4
  Downloading numpy-1.21.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (15.7 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 15.7 MB 41.4 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio<2.0,>=1.24.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.43.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel<1.0,>=0.23.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from astunparse>=1.6.0->tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (0.37.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cached-property in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from h5py>=2.9.0->tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard-data-server<0.7.0,>=0.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorboard<2.9,>=2.8->tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (0.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorboard<2.9,>=2.8->tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorboard<2.9,>=2.8->tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (0.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard-plugin-wit>=1.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorboard<2.9,>=2.8->tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorboard<2.9,>=2.8->tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (3.3.6)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<2.9,>=2.8->tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata>=4.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from markdown>=2.6.8->tensorboard<2.9,>=2.8->tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (4.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from importlib-metadata>=4.4->markdown>=2.6.8->tensorboard<2.9,>=2.8->tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (3.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<2.9,>=2.8->tensorflow~=2.8.0->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: dm-tree~=0.1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow-model-optimization>=0.4.1->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (0.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: crcmod<2.0,>=1.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from apache-beam->object-detection==0.1) (1.7)
Collecting fastavro<2,>=0.21.4
  Downloading fastavro-1.4.9-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (2.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.3 MB 38.1 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: pyarrow<7.0.0,>=0.15.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from apache-beam->object-detection==0.1) (6.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pydot<2,>=1.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from apache-beam->object-detection==0.1) (1.3.0)
Collecting proto-plus<2,>=1.7.1
  Downloading proto_plus-1.19.9-py3-none-any.whl (45 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 45 kB 3.2 MB/s
Collecting requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0
  Downloading requests-2.27.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 63 kB 1.8 MB/s
Collecting dill<0.3.2,>=0.3.1.1
  Downloading dill-0.3.1.1.tar.gz (151 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 151 kB 44.4 MB/s
Collecting numpy>=1.15.4
  Downloading numpy-1.20.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (15.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 15.3 MB 21.1 MB/s
Collecting orjson<4.0
  Downloading orjson-3.6.6-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl (245 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 245 kB 53.2 MB/s
Collecting hdfs<3.0.0,>=2.1.0
  Downloading hdfs-2.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
Collecting pymongo<4.0.0,>=3.8.0
  Downloading pymongo-3.12.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (508 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 508 kB 44.3 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: docopt in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from hdfs<3.0.0,>=2.1.0->apache-beam->object-detection==0.1) (0.6.2)
Collecting protobuf>=3.12.0
  Downloading protobuf-3.19.4-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.1 MB 47.3 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0->google-api-core<3dev,>=1.21.0->google-api-python-client>=1.6.7->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (2.0.11)
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python>=4.1.0.25 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from lvis->object-detection==0.1) (4.1.2.30)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from lvis->object-detection==0.1) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from lvis->object-detection==0.1) (1.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: text-unidecode>=1.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from python-slugify->kaggle>=1.3.9->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: regex in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from sacrebleu->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (2019.12.20)
Requirement already satisfied: tabulate>=0.8.9 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from sacrebleu->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (0.8.9)
Collecting portalocker
  Downloading portalocker-2.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting colorama
  Downloading colorama-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn>=0.21.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from seqeval->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from scikit-learn>=0.21.3->seqeval->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from scikit-learn>=0.21.3->seqeval->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typeguard>=2.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow-addons->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (2.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: promise in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow-datasets->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: future in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow-datasets->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=18.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow-datasets->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (21.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-resources in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow-datasets->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (5.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-metadata in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from tensorflow-datasets->tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.6.0)
Collecting tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem>=0.23.1
  Downloading tensorflow_io_gcs_filesystem-0.24.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (2.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.1 MB 40.9 MB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: object-detection, py-cpuinfo, dill, avro-python3, seqeval
  Building wheel for object-detection (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for object-detection: filename=object_detection-0.1-py3-none-any.whl size=1686316 sha256=775b8c34c800b3b3139d1067abd686af9ce9158011fccfb5450ccfd9bf424a5a
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-rmw0fvil/wheels/d0/e3/e9/b9ffe85019ec441e90d8ff9eddee9950c4c23b7598204390b9
  Building wheel for py-cpuinfo (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for py-cpuinfo: filename=py_cpuinfo-8.0.0-py3-none-any.whl size=22257 sha256=ac956c4c039868fdba78645bea056754e667e8840bea783ad2ca75e4d3e682c6
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/d2/f1/1f/041add21dc9c4220157f1bd2bd6afe1f1a49524c3396b94401
  Building wheel for dill (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for dill: filename=dill-0.3.1.1-py3-none-any.whl size=78544 sha256=d9c6cdfd69aea2b4d78e6afbbe2bc530394e4081eb186eb4f4cd02373ca739fd
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/a4/61/fd/c57e374e580aa78a45ed78d5859b3a44436af17e22ca53284f
  Building wheel for avro-python3 (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for avro-python3: filename=avro_python3-1.10.2-py3-none-any.whl size=44010 sha256=4eca8b4f30e4850d5dabccee36c40c8dda8a6c7e7058cfb7f0258eea5ce7b2b3
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/d6/e5/b1/6b151d9b535ee50aaa6ab27d145a0104b6df02e5636f0376da
  Building wheel for seqeval (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for seqeval: filename=seqeval-1.2.2-py3-none-any.whl size=16180 sha256=0ddfa46d0e36e9be346a90833ef11cc0d38cc7e744be34c5a0d321f997a30cba
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/05/96/ee/7cac4e74f3b19e3158dce26a20a1c86b3533c43ec72a549fd7
Successfully built object-detection py-cpuinfo dill avro-python3 seqeval
Installing collected packages: requests, protobuf, numpy, tf-estimator-nightly, tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, tensorboard, keras, tensorflow, portalocker, dill, colorama, tf-slim, tensorflow-text, tensorflow-model-optimization, tensorflow-addons, seqeval, sentencepiece, sacrebleu, pyyaml, pymongo, py-cpuinfo, proto-plus, orjson, opencv-python-headless, hdfs, fastavro, tf-models-official, tensorflow-io, lvis, avro-python3, apache-beam, object-detection
  Attempting uninstall: requests
    Found existing installation: requests 2.23.0
    Uninstalling requests-2.23.0:
      Successfully uninstalled requests-2.23.0
  Attempting uninstall: protobuf
    Found existing installation: protobuf 3.17.3
    Uninstalling protobuf-3.17.3:
      Successfully uninstalled protobuf-3.17.3
  Attempting uninstall: numpy
    Found existing installation: numpy 1.19.5
    Uninstalling numpy-1.19.5:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.19.5
  Attempting uninstall: tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem
    Found existing installation: tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.23.1
    Uninstalling tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem-0.23.1:
      Successfully uninstalled tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem-0.23.1
  Attempting uninstall: tensorboard
    Found existing installation: tensorboard 2.7.0
    Uninstalling tensorboard-2.7.0:
      Successfully uninstalled tensorboard-2.7.0
  Attempting uninstall: keras
    Found existing installation: keras 2.7.0
    Uninstalling keras-2.7.0:
      Successfully uninstalled keras-2.7.0
  Attempting uninstall: tensorflow
    Found existing installation: tensorflow 2.7.0
    Uninstalling tensorflow-2.7.0:
      Successfully uninstalled tensorflow-2.7.0
  Attempting uninstall: dill
    Found existing installation: dill 0.3.4
    Uninstalling dill-0.3.4:
      Successfully uninstalled dill-0.3.4
  Attempting uninstall: pyyaml
    Found existing installation: PyYAML 3.13
    Uninstalling PyYAML-3.13:
      Successfully uninstalled PyYAML-3.13
  Attempting uninstall: pymongo
    Found existing installation: pymongo 4.0.1
    Uninstalling pymongo-4.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pymongo-4.0.1
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
yellowbrick 1.3.post1 requires numpy<1.20,>=1.16.0, but you have numpy 1.20.3 which is incompatible.
multiprocess 0.70.12.2 requires dill>=0.3.4, but you have dill 0.3.1.1 which is incompatible.
google-colab 1.0.0 requires requests~=2.23.0, but you have requests 2.27.1 which is incompatible.
datascience 0.10.6 requires folium==0.2.1, but you have folium 0.8.3 which is incompatible.
albumentations 0.1.12 requires imgaug<0.2.7,>=0.2.5, but you have imgaug 0.2.9 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed apache-beam-2.35.0 avro-python3-1.10.2 colorama-0.4.4 dill-0.3.1.1 fastavro-1.4.9 hdfs-2.6.0 keras-2.8.0 lvis-0.5.3 numpy-1.20.3 object-detection-0.1 opencv-python-headless-4.5.5.62 orjson-3.6.6 portalocker-2.3.2 proto-plus-1.19.9 protobuf-3.19.4 py-cpuinfo-8.0.0 pymongo-3.12.3 pyyaml-5.4.1 requests-2.27.1 sacrebleu-2.0.0 sentencepiece-0.1.96 seqeval-1.2.2 tensorboard-2.8.0 tensorflow-2.8.0 tensorflow-addons-0.15.0 tensorflow-io-0.24.0 tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem-0.24.0 tensorflow-model-optimization-0.7.0 tensorflow-text-2.8.1 tf-estimator-nightly-2.8.0.dev2021122109 tf-models-official-2.8.0 tf-slim-1.1.0
```

I am noticing that this command uninstalling tensorflow 2.7 and installing tensorflow 2.8. I am not sure it was happening before. Maybe it's the reason DNN library link is missing o something?

I can confirm these:

1. Nothing was changed inside pretrained model or already installed model or object_detection source files I downloaded a year ago.
2. I tried to run command !pip install dnn - not working
3. I tried to restart runtime (without disconnecting) - not working

Somebody can help? Thanks.

Comment: Also I am sure it is running GPU accelerated environment.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: This error is because very recently New Tensorflow version is released 2.8.0. Colab has still default version 2.7.0. When you are trying to install Object detection API, it automatically takes newer version.Do code changes as demands right Tensorflow version. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your cloning the Tensorflow Repo from Github,change the setup.py within ..\models\research\object_detection\packages\tf2 to

```
'tensorflow==2.7.0',
'tf-models-official==2.7.0',
'tensorflow_io==0.23.1',
```

So when you're installing TFOD it will install Tensorflow 2.7 instead 2.8. But make sure to do the changes after you clone the repo from github. Otherwise your changes will be gone

Answer (score 14):

It's worked for me (Colab)

```
# Check libcudnn8 version
!apt-cache policy libcudnn8

# Install latest version
!apt install --allow-change-held-packages libcudnn8=8.4.1.50-1+cuda11.6

# Export env variables
!export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
!export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.4/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
!export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.4/include:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
!export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64

# Install tensorflow
!pip install tflite-model-maker==0.4.0
!pip uninstall -y tensorflow && pip install -q tensorflow==2.9.1
!pip install pycocotools==2.0.4
!pip install opencv-python-headless==4.6.0.66
```

Answer (score 9):

This looks like a compatibility issue with Tensorflow, cuda and models repo code.

Try installing the below TensorFlow version and cuda version at the start of colab.. Should work.

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.8
!apt install --allow-change-held-packages libcudnn8=8.1.0.77-1+cuda11.2
```

Answer (score 7):

For people who have same error: after install object_detection just need to reinstall tensorflow=2.7.0 again by running this command:

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.7.0
```

YOU NEED TO RESTART RUNTIME AFTER THAT (Menu -> Runtime -> Restart Runtime)

This will solve "(0) UNIMPLEMENTED: DNN library is not found" problem

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue. Tried all the solutions, but turns out the python process was still running on my GPU. I had to look up the process id using `nvidia-smi` and kill the process id with

```
kill <process_id>
```

Everything ran smoothly after that.

Answer (score 0):

Before executing train models just execute below command in colab it will resolve DNN library not found in tensorflow 2.8.2

`!apt install --allow-change-held-packages libcudnn8=8.1.0.77-1+cuda11.2`